# asp.net Localized Resources Explicit Localization not loading localized files

Tags: asp.net, .net, localization, resources, explicit

Resources for asp.net for different cultures load when a file with same name exists but with the suffix language-country like for example fr-FR for France.

Used this tutorial to create localized resources with explicit localization:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f(v=vs.80).aspx

But it doesn't load the localized resources (loads the global resources file, the one without the culture name on it).
I setted regional settings to fr (the localized culture that I'm trying altough I'm in Portugal), the localization in regional settings to France, checked the fr-FR language was on top of the IE9 browser languages (on internet options), recompiled the application, cleaned the the folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files, and it still doesn't work.

Also tried to put the fr file into a subdir called fr and using fr-FR instead of fr only.

Why the fr resources are not loading? Maybe I have to change the main file name (how does .net knows what's the main resources file filename)?

Comment: You should edit your question (click on the edit link below it) and add tags relevant to your language / framework (.Net?).

Comment: Edited with new hints and keywords

Comment: As your question is quite old, you might get fewer answers, in which case you can delete it and repost it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of IIS you are using but in 7 you have to explicitly turn on client based culture as detailed [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771836%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). This adds the following line to your web.config

```
<system.web>
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
</system.web>
```

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15313/Globalization-and-localization-demystified-in-ASP) further explains that you also need to set these values in addition:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto" uiculture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
</system.web>
```